# How to change background color based on horizontal scroll position?

Tags: javascript, scroll, background-color, horizontal-scrolling

I’m trying to make my background color change based on the scroll position. I’ve found a lot of tutorials, but the thing is, my website scrolls horizontally so whenever I use the codes I find, it just doesn’t work because they search for the vertical scroll position which is always 0!
I want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cgspicer/V4qh9/s) but with horizontal scroll.

```
  [1]: [http://jsfiddle.net/cgspicer/V4qh9/][1]
```

Comment: Have you tried `window.scrollX`?

Comment: No because I don't know how to do it

Comment: The JSFiddle you have provided seems to not be working. The colour does not change on scroll.

Comment: it does not work because the required libraries are not included!

Comment: Sorry the link was wrong, I meant this one http://jsfiddle.net/cgspicer/V4qh9/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V4qh9/1610/ On line 11 in the js, the scrollTop has been changed to scrollLeft